# change the input of a pre-defined function from a url to a local file

Tags: python

I need to change this function from url input to a local file input

```
def download_and_resize_image(url, new_width=256, new_height=256,display=False):

    _, filename = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix=".jpg")
    response = urlopen(url)
    image_data = response.read()
    image_data = BytesIO(image_data)
    pil_image = Image.open(image_data)
    pil_image = ImageOps.fit(pil_image, (new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    pil_image_rgb = pil_image.convert("RGB")
    pil_image_rgb.save(filename, format="JPEG", quality=90)
    print("Image downloaded to %s." % filename)
    if display:
      display_image(pil_image)
    return filename
```

This code was given to me by my teacher. How can I change the input to a local file?

I looked in the request library but I was not lucky with a function. Is there a predefined function to grab a local file or how /what changes should I make on the predefined function?

Comment: What kind of local input ? `json`,`csv` or `text` file ? Please put sample and input and it's type.

Comment: a local jpg file example frame.jpg

Comment: A URL can refer to a local file via a "file://..." URL. This code might work as is.

Comment: I changed response= urlopen(url)    to    response = cv2.imread(url)  but it didn't work I also tried ''file://....." not working the error is (syntax error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the `filepath` in as the argument and read from `fileapth`. 
Try this.

```
def download_and_resize_image(filepath, new_width=256, new_height=256,display=False):

# _, filename = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix=".jpg")
# response = urlopen(url)
# image_data = response.read()
# image_data = BytesIO(image_data)
pil_image = Image.open(filepath)
pil_image = ImageOps.fit(pil_image, (new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
pil_image_rgb = pil_image.convert("RGB")
pil_image_rgb.save(filename, format="JPEG", quality=90)
print("Image downloaded to %s." % filename)
if display:
display_image(pil_image)
return filename
```

Comment: here is my complete code      (https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zhMRwYr59FUXyhLi0w9YeR9mq1NwodPo)  I get error in the image_file = "...….. line

Comment: You are facing issue with the escape character. Check how to give pah in python. I believe you can solve that.

Answer (score 0):

The Image.open method takes a file-path and a mode. [See here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.x/reference/Image.html#functions). You should be able to replace url with filepath and put that in Image.open

```
pil_image = Image.open(filepath)
```